# Java - mySql database connection

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am new in Java, and i need some help.
From three hours I am fighting with database connection.
First I create project and downloaded drivers and extract it to my project folder.
After this found some code, update by my database adress, username, password and put in in my project.
Now i have one file: MysqlConnect.java :

```
  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jdbc;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
*/
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBC {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // LADOWANIE STEROWNIKA
    System.out.print("Sprawdzanie sterownika:");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Blad przy ladowaniu sterownika bazy!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.print(" sterownik OK");

    // LACZENIE Z BAZA
    System.out.print("\nLaczenie z baza danych:");
    String baza = "jdbc:mysql://db41032162719.db.1and1.com/db41032162719";
    // objasnienie opisu bazy:
    // jdbc: - mechanizm laczenia z baza (moze byc inny, np. odbc)
    // mysql: - rodzaj bazy
    // //olimp.if.pw.edu.pl - adres serwera z baza (moze byc tez w formie adresu IP)
    // /pojava - nazwa bazy (poniewaz na serwerze moze byc kilka roznych baz...)
    String user = "dbo41032162719";
    String pass = "Zasypiam3141";
    java.sql.Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(baza, user, pass);
        //rownoznacze z zapisem:
        //conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://olimp.if.pw.edu.pl/pojava?user=pojava&password=Java");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Blad przy ladowaniu sterownika bazy!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.print(" polaczenie OK\n");

    // WYKONYWANIE OPERACJI NA BAZIE DANYCH
    System.out.println("Pobieranie danych z bazy:");
    Statement s = null;
    try {
        s = conn.createStatement();   // tworzenie obiektu Statement przesylajacego zapytania do bazy conn
        ResultSet r;                
        r=s.executeQuery("Select * from meteo;");  // wykonanie kwerendy i przeslanie wynikow do obiektu ResultSet  
        r.next();           // przejscie do kolejnego rekordu (wiersza) otrzymanych wynikow

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = r.getMetaData();
        int numcols = rsmd.getColumnCount();   // pobieranie liczby kolumn

        //wyswietlanie nazw kolumn:
        for (int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++) { 
         System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)+"  |  "); 
        }
        System.out.print("\n------------------------------------\n");

        //wyswietlanie kolejnych rekordow:
        while (r.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++) {
                 Object obj = r.getObject(i);
                 if (obj != null)System.out.print(obj.toString()+ " | ");
                 else  System.out.print(" ");
               }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Blad odczytu z bazy! " +e.toString());
        System.exit(3);
    }

    // ZAMYKANIE POLACZENIA Z BAZA
    System.out.print("\nZamykanie polaczenia z baza:");
    try {
        s.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Blad przy zamykaniu polaczenia " +e.toString());
        System.exit(4);
    }
    System.out.print(" zamkniecie OK");
}
```

}

And i have error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at jdbc.JDBC.main(JDBC.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -     com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver is not abstract and does not override abstract method     getParentLogger() in java.sql.Driver
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:69)
    ... 3 more
Sprawdzanie sterownika:Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

I looking something about solving my problem on internet bout all of it doesnt work :(
If someone help me i will be obliged.
I think the problem isn't in code, because i tried three anodher codes from google and all make same error. I put my error in google, but it was only 1 result from Russian site..

Comment: That method was introduced in Java 1.7. Try executing on a Java 1.6 environment. I however wonder why it failed for you. Even though the most recent MySQL JDBC JAR file 5.1.8 is written for Java 1.6, it should work as good in Java 1.7. How exactly are you compiling/executing it? Using some IDE? Wasn't you or the IDE extracting the MySQL JAR file and repackaging/recompiling all its contents against Java 1.7 for some unclear reason?

Comment: I using Netbeans IDE 7.1.
I add mysql-onnector-java-5.1.18.zip to libraries in left panel on Netbeans, also i put all folders from zip in my package folder.

Comment: @user1304098: Did any of the comments/answers help?  Did you solve the problem on your own?

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://www.java-forums.org/java-applets/45434-error-connection-mysql.html , your probably have a mismatch between your JRE and the version of the driver you're using.

What version of each are you using?  What version of the JRE was the driver compiled against?

EDIT...
You mentioned that you're using mysql conector/j 5.1.18 with JRE 1.7.  According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-versions-java.html, mysql 5.1 is supported only on JRE/JDK 1.5 and 1.6.  If you compile & run with the correct version, you will probably get rid of the exception.

Comment: Mysql connector 5.1.18, and what is JRE? I use NetBeans IDE 7.1

Comment: Both versions are the latest.

Comment: @user1304098 JRE = Java Runtime Environment, it refers to the Java Virtual Machine + the standard Java libraries. You can check the version of your default JRE by running "java -version" on the command line. Here's the command line reference if you're on Windows: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: My version of JRE is 1.7.0_02

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-versions-java.html has the supported Java versions for mysql connector/j.  Looks like you do, in fact, have a version mismatch.

Comment: This is exactly the problem.  The driver you're using is pre-jdk 1.7.  With jdk 1.7, all drivers have to implement the getParentLogger() method.  Yours didn't, ergo it's pre-jdk1.7.  One small feature of jdk 1.7 that is not backward compatible.